# Comparing two optionals in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Consider a class with id field which might be null until stored in database:

```
class IdableK<T : IdableK<T>> : Comparable<T> {    
    private var id : Long? = null
}
```

I am trying to implement a `compareTo` method as follows:

```
    override fun compareTo(other: T): Int {
        if (id == null) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (other.id == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        return id!!.compareTo(other.id!!)
    }
```

Is this a correct way of doing it? Would there be a simple way of doing it?

Comment: What may happen if both of them is `null`? You are breaking the symmetric contract.

Comment: That is a design problem, this is just an example, I am trying to solve a programming problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [kotlin.comparisons package](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/index.html). e.g. You can use [`compareValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-values.html):

```
class IdableK<T : IdableK<T>> : Comparable<T> {
    private var id: Long? = null

    override fun compareTo(other: T) = compareValues(id, other.id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect. If you have two instances with their ids set to `null`, both instances will return `-1` when you call `compareTo(other)` on them, while if one returns `-1` the other should return `1` in a correct implementation. I'm not sure if there are situations where it makes sense to implement `compareTo` based on nullable properties, but I can't imagine any. Maybe there's a better way for you too?

Also, you should avoid non-null assertions (`!!`). Since you're using `var`s, other threads may change the value to null so that even if you did a null check  before, the value is now null and `!!` throws. Instead, you should store both ids in local variables and check these for `null` values.

If you absolutely have to use `compareTo`, I'd do it like this:

```
override fun compareTo(other: T): Int {
    val thisId = id
    val otherId = other.id
    if (thisId == null && otherId == null) return 0
    if (thisId == null && otherId != null) return -1
    if (thisId != null && otherId == null) return 1

    // thisId and otherId are now smart cast to Long
    return thisId.compareTo(otherId)
}
```

Comment: I think it can make sense to compare nullable properties, you might want to sort the instances that have them as `null` to one of the ends of a list, for example. If comparing two instances that both have it as `null`, obviously `0` should be returned (as you've done in your example), and then it's all good and sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way:

```
override fun compareTo(other: T) :Int {
    return id?.compareTo(other.id ?: return 1) ?: -1
}
```

However this piece of code is very unfriendly to a novice kotlin programmer. It involves too much magic that make it look like scala. These 3 question marks make people puzzled, at least they must think for a minute or two before they could realize what is going on in this minimalistic one-liner. I still prefer your edition. It's more verbose, but clear.

And I'm really worried about the symmetric problem. This matters, and isn't just a design problem. If you don't compare nullable properties, there won't be this programming puzzle. It will just be `override fun compareTo(other: T) = id.compareTo(other.id)`. Simple, clear, and no misleading.

I would rather throw away all null checking code and just live with those null assertions. Because mostly you won't compare there things until it is fully initialized. If these assertion fails, it means something really bad has happens.

Oh, BTW, I don't know about your project, and if it hits the rare cases that you have to compare nullable properties, I think you could write a special edition of `Comparator` that consider nulls instead of throwing NPEs. Don't mess with the natural order.